# /opt/vc/src/hello_pi missing

Tags: framebuffer

I am learning c programming for the Raspberry framebuffer through the book "Raspberry Pi Computer Architecture Essentials" by Andrew Dennis.  The Raspbian OS originally provided with my RPi 3 came with C source code examples in /opt/vc/src/hello_pi but the Raspbian OS for my RPi 4 omits this library.  And I don't find anything under Preferences>Recommended Software to obtain hello_pi demos.  With the transition from VideoCodeIV to VideoCoreVI were the hello_pi demo programs removed? What's the sudo apt-get command for the current hello_pi suite?

Comment: My install of RaspiOS Bookworm aarch64 has a copy of `/opt/vc/src/*` installed on it by default. That includes `hello-pi`. So are you using that version of RaspiOS?

Answer (score 0):

The Pi4 uses a different SOC with many differences from earlier models.

The latest OS Bullseye no longer uses the  proprietary vc drivers.

If you want to use these you MAY have some luck with legacy Buster.

Comment: I understand that the Buster vc driver only supported 16 bits per pixel but I'm trying to use the 24 or 32 bpp available with some Pi4 C source code examples but I cannot find any such.  My starting point was www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/screen01.html  Any URL suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Again, I was trying to teach myself C and RPi graphics programming by reading books (including a good one by Jan Newmarch) and by reverse-engineering the hello_pi sample programs.  I assumed that with Bullseye some of the Khronos interfaces to the GPU's might have to change and that Bullseye hello_pi would provide a key to those changes.